# GXT : destroying Dialogbox didn't work

Tags: java, gwt, gxt, gwt2

I have a Dialogbox class:

```
public class Dialogbox {

    public static final Window dialogbox = new Window();

    public Dialogbox() {
        dialogbox.setAnimateMinimize(true);

        dialogbox.setWidth(469);
        dialogbox.setHeight(487);
        dialogbox.setShowMinimizeButton(true);
        dialogbox.setAutoSize(true);
        dialogbox.setCanDragReposition(true);
        dialogbox.setCanDragResize(true);
        dialogbox.setIsModal(true);
        // dialogbox.setShowModalMask(true);
        dialogbox.addCloseClickHandler(new CloseClickHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onCloseClick(CloseClientEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                dialogbox.destroy();
            }
        });

    }

    public void show(Widget name, String txt) {
        dialogbox.setTitle(txt);
        dialogbox.addItem(name);
        dialogbox.setPadding(10);
        AnimationCallback callback = null;
        dialogbox.animateMove(400, 100, callback, 1000);


        dialogbox.show();

    }
```

When I try a Composite:

```
f list = new f();
dia.show(f, "price");
```

I get the error:

```
[ERROR] 15:34:20.020:WARN:Canvas:isc_WidgetCanvas_1:Attempt to access destroyed widget in the DOM - destroy() called at invalid time (eg: mid-draw) or invalid method called on destroy()d widget. Stack Trace:
```

My in-Box Composite is a Widget:

```
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
    canvas.addChild(btnNewButton);
    initWidget(canvas);
```

Why can't I destroy my Dialogbox? Do I have to remove the widget first?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want just hide the Dialog box,
then you can use
 `dialogbox.hide()`
Where as, if you want to delete the Dialog box,
then you can Detach/Delete it from it's Parent element by using

```
dialogbox.removeFromParent()
```

But, as my expectation you just want to hide the Dialog Box.

Here, I gave two ways, you can use it based on your requirement.

Comment: if remove as like `dialogbox.removeFromParent` , can I use it again ?

Comment: Obviously, No. If you want to use it again, you have to add it to it's parent agin.

Answer (score 0):

Use `dialogbox.hide()` if you want to hide dialog box.

Comment: thx, i tested it with a clear bevor i Add a new item and it worked